# How to implement a replacing strings in Text with DropdownButton?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I'm new to Flutter, learning on my own. I am making an application project with books.
On the book page there is a Header Banner, below it a **DropdownButton** and the text of the book chapter.

The text of the chapters is moved to a separate class of Strings (**Vincenco**) and is implemented through the **Text**.

Question: how to make the **DropdownButton** change the String (*texto1*) to another String (*texto2*)?

*P.s. 'texto1a' and 'texto2a' - these are the titles of the chapter of the book above the text of the chapter*

```
 class _BookMainWidgetState extends State<BookMainWidget> {

  String texto1 = Vincenco.v1;
  String texto1a = Vincenco.v1a;
  String texto2 = Vincenco.v2;
  String texto2a = Vincenco.v2a;

  var _locations = [
    'Глава 1',
    'Глава 2',
    'Глава 3',
    'Глава 4',
    'Глава 5',
  ];
  var _currentItemSelected = 'Глава 1';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16, vertical: 8),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  border: Border.all(color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2)),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2),
                      blurRadius: 8,
                      offset: Offset(0, 3),
                    ),
                  ],),
                clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                child: Row(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              DropdownButton(
                                  hint: Text(' Выберите главу...'),
                                  isExpanded: true,
                                  onChanged: (newValue) {},
                                  value: _currentItemSelected,
                                  items: _locations.map((
                                      String dropDownStringItem) {
                                    return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                                      value: dropDownStringItem,
                                      child: new Text(dropDownStringItem),
                                    );
                                  }).toList()
                              ),
                              SizedBox(height: 10),
                              Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                          8.0),
                                      child:
                                      Text(texto1a,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.brown,
                                            fontSize: 16,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                .bold),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(
                                          8.0),
                                      child:
                                      Text(texto1,
                                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight
                                                .bold),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ]
                              ),
```

Comment: https://codesinsider.com/flutter-dropdown-button-example/

Comment: The construction of the DropdownButton is clear to me. I am interested in how to make it change the value of the text in another widget

Comment: so you want that whatever is selected in the dropdown will appear in place of previous text?

Comment: Yes exactly. The selected dropdown item changed the text content to the corresponding fragment